# Change language in facebook account kit in ios

Tags: ios, localization, account-kit

I want to localization in **facebook account kit**.

when I change app language to Arabic but **account kit can't change** the language to Arabic.
**it is still in English**.

so can anyone tell me how I can change the language in account kit?

Comment: Hi, @darsh Did you get any solution?

Comment: No, I didn't  find any solution